# Extract interfaces in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, interface, refactoring

I have extracted interfaces from my JPA entity classes.

1. How can I let Eclipse use the super type (the interface of the entity) in all other projects (not only in the JPA project to access the database) in the workspace where it is possible? E. g. "EntityImpl entity = new EntityImpl();" should be -> "Entity entity = new EntityImpl();" or "checkEntity(EntityImpl entity)" should be -> "checkEntity(Entity entity)"
2. How can I refactor the @see tag in "(non-javadoc)" comments on overriden methods? E. g. "@see OldEntityClassName.method(...)" -> "@see Entity.method(...)"

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click EntityImpl, then Refactor -> User Supertype Where Possible. This should replace code in dependent projects as well.
2. There's a setting controlling comment generation for overridden methods in Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates -> Overriding Methods. This controls new methods only though. If you need to process existing @see tags then Eclipse doesn't support it out of the box. Not sure if there's some 3rd party plugin to do it.

Comment: 1. works, thanks. Maybe some one else knowns a plugin to fix @see tags?

Comment: Idea: I can remove all "(non-javadoc)" comments using a regular expression. Is it possible to let Eclipse recreate all comments without open every *.java file and press ctrl + alt + j?

Comment: Not possible as far as I know. Your best shot is writing a script or a small plugin that hooks into JDT code and modifies the sources.